# Is it possible to draw chart with web worker

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, web-worker

Is it possible to draw the D3.js bubble chart using web workers ??

I am getting unresponsive script error while loading JSON data of more than 2 mb into the browser ??

Can any one tell how can I make it possible ??

Comment: At what point does the browser get unresponsive? Is it when it parses the JSON, or after it's done that?

Comment: I think its during parsing